# Unit Testing of Google Task API

Tags: java, google-app-engine, unit-testing, mocking, google-api

I am developing web application that uses Google Task API. I've a class that use Task Service API. My intention is to unit test my code by mocking the underlying Google API Infrastructure. I attempted to do the following:

```
 MockHttpTransport httpTransport = new MockHttpTransport();
 MockJsonFactory jsonFactory = new MockJsonFactory();
 Credential credential = new Credential.Builder(
            BearerToken.queryParameterAccessMethod()).setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
            .setTokenServerUrl(TOKEN_SERVER_URL)
            .setClientAuthentication(new BasicAuthentication(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET))
            .build();


    Tasks service = new Tasks.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).build();
```

But I am not sure how to pass the sample JSON file in these set of mock classes. I am struck with the error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no JSON input found.

After googling a bit, I found there seems a way in Python world of the same API:

```
http = HttpMock('./data/only_one_task.json', {'status': '200'})
```

But looking for way to achieve the same in Java. Any help/pointers very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and replaced `new MockJsonFactory()` with `GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance()`.